# Give an example of a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies all three conditions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, examples-counterexamples

Give an example of a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies all three conditions

1. $f$  is bijective
2. $f'(0)=0$
3. the inverse function $f^{-1}$ is not continuous at $0$

Does $f(x)=x^3$ satisfy the all three conditions?

If not can any provide me an example?

Comment: what mean $f^{-1}$? $1/f(x)$ or $f^{-1}(x)$?

Comment: that mean inverse of the given function

Comment: Does the function need to be differentiable everywhere, or only at $0$?

Comment: If $f$ need not be continuous away from $0$, define $f$ in a piecewise manner, such as $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x^3, & |x| < 1 \\ -x, & |x| \geq 1 \end{cases} $$ Also notice that a bijective continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ must have a continuous inverse, which necessitates discontinuity of any such example $f$.

Comment: @SangchulLee The inverse of that is still continuous at zero. The basic idea works, but you have to move the discontinuity in some way. Adding one to all values of $f$ works, as I did in my answer.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta, Ah, I carelessly read the question and happened to misread the condition 3. I agree with your point. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the last condition fails.
The inverse $f^{-1}(y)=\sqrt[3]y$ is continuous at zero.

What would work, then?
We want things to be nice at $x=0$ but not nice at the point where $f(x)=0$.
Therefore we don't want $f(0)=0$.
Your function $x\mapsto x^3$ only fails the third condition.
To remedy this, we change it to $x\mapsto x^3+1$.

Now all we have to do is to modify this function at $x=-1$ and maybe elsewhere far from $x=0$ to make the inverse discontinuous.
This is easiest to do by swapping two values:
$$
f(x)
=
\begin{cases}
x^3+1,&x\neq\pm1\\
0,&x=+1\\
2,&x=-1
\end{cases}
$$
Draw a picture, and it should become clear why this works.

Comment: ..then you sir give me example that satisfies all conditions

Comment: ....thank but can i get what is the inverse of f

Comment: @LearingMath I gave an example. In the future, please remember to ask nicely. People don't like taking orders online for no reward. I also recommend taking a look at our [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour). // To your second comment: You can work out the inverse if you draw a picture. The function is essentially $x^3+1$ with modifications at just two points.